# Pure js invoking functions on async script (external file) within body tags

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, invoke

I am writing a script using pure js involving a js snippet that is copied into cleint websites. When invoking a pure js function myfunction() like below the function will run, no need for document.ready, onload etc:

```
<body>  
   <script>
  function myfunction(){}
  myfunction()

   </script>     
</body>
```

So my question is if I load an external file like this below, will the js function execute with simply myfunction() and  across all browsers.

```
 <body>  
   <script type="text/javascript"async=""src="anotherwebsite.com/jsfile.js"></script> 
</body>
```

jsfile.js contents

```
 function myfunction(){}
  myfunction()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens If you dynamically load in a `<script>` tag it will be executed asynchronous by default. So the code will be executed and `myfunction` will be invoked. If you want your code to be synchronously you can set the `async` attribute to false like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" async="false" src="anotherwebsite.com/jsfile.js" ></script>
```

More on async in [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).